# Create range in SQL Server join another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table

First fact table

```
Sku        Sales
001        100.000
002        500.000
003        0
004        1.500.000
005        5.400.000
006        7.000.000
007        8.000.000
008        3.000.000
009        7.000.000
010        8.000.000
```

Second table Products

```
Sku        Style
001        ABC
002        ABC
003        ABC
004        DEF
005        GHI
006        JKL
007        MNO
008        MNO
009        PQR
010        PQR
```

and I want to create table with the result like this

```
Style      Sales       Range
ABC        600.000     0 -0,9 mio
DEF        1.500.000   1 mio - 4,9 mio
GHI        5.400.000   5 mio - 9,9 mio
JKL        7.000.000   5 mio - 9,9 mio
MON        11.000.000  10 mio - 19,9 mio
PQR        15.000.000  10 mio - 19,9 mio
```

and also I want to have result like this

```
Range                No of Style
0 - 0,9 mio          1
1 mio - 4,9 mio      1
5 mio - 9,9 mio      2
10 mio - 19,9 mio    2
```

How to implement?
the style must be SUM first and then calculate range

Comment: How would you get Range if No of Style is 1 or 2? There are 2 entries each for No of style. Whats the logic to get range? Please clarify

Comment: I want to grouping by sales range and by style. For Ex : range 5 - 9,9 mio have 2 styles (GHI and JKL)
And also I already set my range (Upper and limit), 0 - 0,9, 1 - 4,9 and so on